# doing unsigned char arithmetic in python

Tags: python

Goodday,
 I need to port the following C code in Python, but I can't find a good way to do the unsigned char arithmetic that ignores the overflow bits in python, ie. 255+1=0; 255+2=1 etc.
The code below is used in a checksum calculation for a protocol that is implemented in C on the Arduino that I need to interface with.

```
 unsigned char b[length];
 unsigned char c1=0,c2=0,c3=0,c4=0;
 for (i=0; i<length;i++)
 {
  c1+=b[i];
  c2+=c1;
  c3+=c2;
  c4+=c3;
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python there is no notion of signed/unsigned. If you want to handle overflow, you can simply use modular arithmetic.

```
(255 + 1) % 256 = 0
(250 + 2) % 256 = 252
(255 + 5) % 256 = 4
```

Answer (score 3):

You may use `% 256`:

```
>>> (255 + 1) % 256
0
>>> (255 + 2) % 256
1
```

With your example, if `b` is a Python string:

```
>>> b = "thisisatest"
>>> c1, c2, c3, c4 = 0, 0, 0, 0
>>> for c in b:
...     c1 = (c1 + ord(c)) % 256
...     c2 = (c2 + c1) % 256
...     c3 = (c3 + c2) % 256
...     c4 = (c4 + c3) % 256
... 
>>> c1, c2, c3, c4
... (181, 36, 46, 174)
```

Comment: The only reason I didn't add this as an answer, is that the use of ord(c) is not good (IMHO) as the data will be raw non-printable data bits on the wire. That is the reason I used unsigned char[] for b. The answer I chose was for generic reasons ;)

Comment: `ord()` will work with "raw non-printable data": `ord('\x00') == 0` (`\x00` is a null byte).

Answer (score 1):

You can also use bitwise AND, which might be clearer.  I also like hex notation for this.

```
255 & 0xff
256 & 0xff
257 & 0xff
-1 & 0xff
```

Comment: I'm upvoting this one, but it should be a shared answer ;)